# Extending site width according to the image size

Tags: css, images

The WordPress theme is for a comic reading site. Since image cannot be re sized because the text will be distorted, I need to extend the site width according to the image size in the post.

Here is the URL: http://myreadingmanga.info/wordpress/?p=1578

**Image re size should not be done, but site expansion should be. Anyone can help with this?**

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a responsive theme that can handle wide pages gracefully. I don't think there is any simple hack that will not break your theme if it was not designed for it.

A saner option is to show a scaled down image that fits your theme and open the full image when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking but try setting the image to a fixed width and height, then set the width of the parent container to 100% with a min-width equal to the image width.

```
yourImg {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}

yourContainerDiv {
  width:100%;
  min-width:300px;
}
```